# what does this message mean?

Tags: nautilus

(org.gnome.Nautilus:58350): GVFS-WARNING **: 00:32:54.981: The peer-to-peer connection failed: Error when getting information for file “/run/user/1001/gvfsd”: No such file or directory. Falling back to the session bus. Your application is probably missing --filesystem=xdg-run/gvfsd privileges.

Comment: I don’t mean this rudely, but the message is pretty clear. It says it couldn’t file a file/directory it expected to find, and it includes a potential solution (at the end of the message). What exactly doesn’t make sense? If you’re a bit more specific, we may be able to give you a better answer. It’s also a warning, not an error, so you may be able to ignore it and be fine (though without more context, that may or may not be true)

Comment: Sorry the terseness was due to my frustration. I ran apt-get install freetuxtv and it hosed my system. The error question is about /run/user/1001/gvfsd I don't have a user 1001 and don't understand the peer-to-peer part. I am the only user on this box

Comment: I get the same message when trying to save an annotated PDF from evince. I guess the question should be rephrased to ask for a solution. I know file system rights expressed as variations of rwx for all, group and owner, but referring to such privileges in the error message is self explaining at all.